# IBM Worklight - How to re-use a function in a multipage app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ibm-mobilefirst

I have used the function `doTimer()` on the page level-one-1, and now I'm trying to reuse the function `doTimer()` on the second page. But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Here is my javascript and html code.

The JS:

```
var start = new Date().getTime(); 
var elapsed = '0.0'; 
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount() {
    var time = new Date().getTime() - start;
    elapsed = Math.floor(time / 100) / 10; 
    if(Math.round(elapsed) == elapsed) { elapsed += '.0'; } 
    document.getElementById('txt').value=elapsed;
    t=setTimeout("timedCount()",50);
}

function doTimer() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        start = new Date().getTime(); 
        timer_is_on=1;
        timedCount();
    }
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on=0;
}

function resetCount() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value='0.0';
    var elapsed = '0.0';
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!-- Page Level 1-1 start --> 
<div id="level-one-1" data-role="page"  >

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>StarKids</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td id="level-1">Level 1</td>
        <td colspan="3" id="center-top"></td>
        <td id="txt">

        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="settings">Setting</td>
        <td colspan="3" id="center-top">Which animal is monkey?</td>
        <td id="overallscore"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td colspan="2"><a onclick="checkAnswer1a()"><img id="tortoise" src="images/duck.png" ></a></td>
        <td><img id="elephant" src="images/duck.png" onclick="checkAnswer1a()"></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img id="giraffe" src="images/duck.png" onclick="checkAnswer1a()"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td colspan="2"><img id="monkey" src="images/duck.png" onclick="checkAnswer1a()"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><img id="owl" src="images/duck.png" onclick="checkAnswer1a()"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" id="next"><a href="#level-one-2" onclick="stopCount();">Next</a></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <!--  Copyright &copy; anitaagustina 2013 -->
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Page Level 1-1 end -->

<!-- Page Level 1-2 start --> 
<div id="level-one-2" data-role="page" onload="doTimer()">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>StarKids</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content" >

    <table id="tabel-soal">

      <tr>
        <td id="level-1">Level 1</td>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="txt">



        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="settings">Setting</td>
        <td colspan="3">Match each word to its picture</td>
        <td id="overallscore"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>image:elephant</td>
        <td>image:elephant</td>
        <td>image:elephant</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>empty-box</td>
        <td>empty-box</td>
        <td>empty-box</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>answer-choice-1</td>
        <td>answer-choice-2</td>
        <td>answer-choice-3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Next</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <!--  Copyright &copy; anitaagustina 2013 -->
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Page Level 1-2 end -->
```

Comment: please elaborate from the begining. what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Put the code in a JS file and include the file?

Comment: So, I'm trying to run the stopwatch in other page but the code only run once on the first page. When I load the next page, the code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This HTML page does not look like an HTML page in a Worklight application. At all.

Comment: How do you navigate between pages? where is the jQuery? Please show an appropriate Worklight-generated HTML file with your content.

Comment: Also, this looks like jQuery Mobile, not regular jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not mention in WHICH .js file you have placed this function *nor how do you navigate between pages*. **This is crucial information. Add this information to your question.**

In the context of a *Worklight 6.1* application - *without knowing anything else about your project* - my suggestion is to place this function in the `common\js\main.js` file. This `main.js` file is referenced in the `HEAD` of your Worklight application's `index.html` file.

To reuse this function, you can then for example navigate between "pages" by replacing the contents of a DIV within the `index.html` file by using jQuery's `load` API method. This way the function is always available no matter which "page" you are loading.

These are two sample projects that implement "page" loading:

- [JQM_multipage_load_changePage.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4kocwo205s049b/JQM_multipage_load_changePage.zip) - uses either `.load` or `.changePage`
- [JQM_multipage_changePage_pageshow.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f0xr9ogp4ofuqs/JQM_multipage_changePage_pageshow.zip) - uses `.changePage` and `.pageShow`

---

Edit: using the provided demo project in the comments to this answer, I have changed the following in it:

1. Change this:

   > ```
   > $(document).on("pageshow", "#one", function( event ) {
   >     alert( "page 1 loaded" );
   > });
   >
   > $(document).on("pageshow", "#two", function( event ) {
   >     alert( "page 2 loaded" );
   > });
   > ```

   To this:

   > ```
   > $(document).on("pageshow", "#one", function( event ) {
   >     alert( "page 1 loaded" );
   >     stopCount();
   >     doTimer();
   > });
   >
   > $(document).on("pageshow", "#two", function( event ) {
   >     alert( "page 2 loaded" );
   >     stopCount();
   >     doTimer();
   > });
   > ```

   To verify `doTimer()` is indeed called, you can add an alert inside `doTimer()`, like `alert ("in doTimer");`

   To verify `stopCount()` is indeed called, you can add an alert inside `doTimer()`, like `alert ("in stopCount");`
2. Remove the `onload` from the HTML:

   From:

   > `<div id="level-one-2" data-role="page" onload="doTimer()">`

   To:

   > `<div id="level-one-2" data-role="page">`

Comment: I've updated my html code. I put the js in the main.js, but it does not recognize the function.

Comment: This is still not the full HTML file in a Worklight application. Can you just export the project from Eclipse and provide a download link from Dropbox?

Comment: I'm not able to provide the project because of some causes. But i'm wondering, where should I put the onload function? Because if I put it on the body, the code works only in a single page, but if I put the function in each of the page, the code does not work.

Comment: Again, if you would explain how you switch pages it will help.

Comment: I use the a href function to switch to the second page. <a href="#level-one-2" onclick="stopCount();">Next</a>. Then, on the second page, <div id="level-one-2" data-role="page" onload="doTimer()">

Comment: this "second" page is a physical second HTML file?

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. I provide there 2 sample project the navigate between pages; you can use this as a training template.

Comment: I've changed the navigation to $.mobile.changePage. but still the stopwatch function doesn't work. But, thanks for the help.

Comment: Then it is time for you to provide something more substantial to work with, like a new demo project, not yours, but similar enough, so it can be used.

Comment: I've changed them, and when I try to run the code, the stopwatch function doesn't work again. I tried to inspect the element, and it said that the function is not defined although I have included the js file.

Comment: How do you expect stopwatch() to work when you are not calling it anywhere? When is it supposed to be run? Who is supposed to call it? comon.... and the same is true for resetCount which is not being called by anything either.

Comment: I thought doTimer() can be used to run the stopwatch. Can it?Well, it is supposed to run in every page. Before I moved the js to js file, I tried to put both of the stopCount() and resetCount() on the button next(a onload="stopCount();resetCOunt();". It does stop and reset, but when I navigate to the next page, the doTimer() isn't working. It supposed to work everytime we called the function right? and after I move it to the js file, all the js function is not defined, although I included the js file, and called them using the <body onload="doTimer()">
sorry for asking too much questions.

Comment: I do not quite follow what you want to do in your app, but look in my edited answer. As you can see there, every time you enter a new page it will stopCount() and then doTimer(). Play with the logic of your app to do your bidding.

Comment: Thanks @Idan for helping me :) I've come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally come up with a solution.

Since I'm new to jquerymobile, I just knew that for multipage app, all of the pages are loaded via  AJAX which is the problem why all of my function stop working when I navigated to other page. So before, I used mobile changepage to navigate, and now I changed them using href="#nextpage" and I added another attribute of data-rel="external". And now it's finally working.

my reference : 
http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/