# IBM Worklight - Javascript Function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using jquerymobile 1.3.2.
My problem is, At first, I put my script on the head part, and all the function works fine, except it can't be re-use in other page. Then, I moved the script to its own javascript page, then I have included the js file, but when I tried to run it on a mobile simulator, all of the function doesn't work. I tried to inspect it, it said "uncaught reference error: doTimer function is not defined". I tried to verify whether the js file is loaded with alert(), and the alert works, but anything else doesn't.

I've checked all other related questions and none of the solution can solve this.

Here is my javascript and html code.

The JS:

```
var start = new Date().getTime(); 
var elapsed = '0.0'; 
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount() {
    var time = new Date().getTime() - start;
    elapsed = Math.floor(time / 100) / 10; 
    if(Math.round(elapsed) == elapsed) { elapsed += '.0'; } 
    document.getElementById('txt').value=elapsed;
    t=setTimeout("timedCount()",50);
}

function doTimer() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        start = new Date().getTime(); 
        timer_is_on=1;
        timedCount();
    }
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on=0;
}

function resetCount() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value='0.0';
    var elapsed = '0.0';
}
```

The HTML:

Page 1

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Test 1</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
  </div>

</div>
```

The second page content is similar to the first one.
And here is my included script which I put below the html code with other script such as

```
    <script src="js/StarKids.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I do believe I have already explained that you Worklight's Single Page Application concept in your previous question about the same code(!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729045/ibm-worklight-how-to-re-use-a-function-in-a-multipage-app

Comment: What do you mean by "I moved the script to its own javascript page"? Those last three script elements? Are they included on the same page as the rest of your HTML?

Comment: @Idan yes, I encounter a different problem now, the function is not defined.

Comment: @Simon I mean, at first I put the script on the html head part, and then I moved it to its own file. The initOptions.js and messages.js are also also on the different file. It's a single page with multiple div page.

Comment: Review what I wrote to you in the previous question. Please, before you develop your application UNDERSTAND THE CONCEPT of multipage in Worklight.

Comment: If you insist on making mistakes, then provide the WHOLE Worklight project or a demo of it. No more code snippets.

Comment: @Idan Here is the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq067m0euzy3jc0/Starkid1.zip Sorry for making so much mistakes. Kinda new to worklight.

Comment: You've uploaded the generated Android project; Upload the Worklight project.

Comment: Here is, sorry before https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ysj3kceg866gdez/STwDuAkztW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the same code from your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729045/ibm-worklight-how-to-re-use-a-function-in-a-multipage-app), that is, there is no event to capture the navigation between "pages" and thus there is no reset of the timers... I suggest that you take note of this before asking why it doesn't work when you're navigating between pages.

Anyway, the problem this time around is that you're defining all of your functions inside `wlCommonInit()`...
Instead change it (for all functions) to something as follows...

What this code snippet means is that once the application starts (`wlCommonInit()`), it will call `doTimer()`, `doTimer()` calls `timedCount()` and so on...

```
// global vars
var start
var elapsed = '0.0'; 
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function wlCommonInit(){
    doTimer();
}


function doTimer() {
    alert("In doTimer()");   
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        start = new Date().getTime(); 
        timer_is_on = 1;
       timedCount();
    }
}

function timedCount() {
    alert ("In timeCounted) 
    var time = new Date().getTime() - start;
    elapsed = Math.floor(time / 100) / 10; 
    if(Math.round(elapsed) === elapsed) { elapsed += '.0'; } 
    document.getElementById('space').value=elapsed;
    t = setTimeout("timedCount()",50);
}
```

Comment: I thought that all the function must be put inside the wlCommonInit.. Now I get it, Thank you so much, Idan!